# how to add policy file for the following in jaas

Tags: java, tomcat, authorization, jaas, java-security

Am learning JAAS authorization.. I have 2 users admin and clients for admin the files associated with it are admin.java and adminfunctions.java and the principal name for admin is admin and for clients its clientservlet.java and reserve.java and the principal name is clients.. so how to write a policy file which restricts and allow access to only the allowed files..

when i searched the net i got this

```
grant codebase "file:./SampleAction.jar",
    Principal javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal 
        "your_user_name@your_realm"  {

   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.home", "read";
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.home", "read";
   permission java.io.FilePermission "foo.txt", "read";
};
```

yet i dont know what kewwrbros is doing and what to write in the place of "your_user_name@your_realm"